# Vue style (background-image) binding not reactive

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, computed-properties, computed-style

I want to change some part of the site based on selected language without any refresh. All worked but I have tried multiple ways to **bind background-image dynamically** on no refresh site language change (i18n). But no success.

```
<div :style="{'background-image' : mainBackground}">
     test div
</div>
```

I have created a computed to return currently used link based on language.

```
mainBackground(){
    return this.isTurkishSite ? 'url(/images/home/home_bg_main_tr.jpg);' : 'url(/images/home/home_bg_main.jpg);'
}
```

But after change site language by dropdown all other  **elements src are updated** to use the selected language image file. **But only this background path is not updating**. Also style attribute is deleted on the element itself. I can not figure out why this solution not worked properly. Also rendered `mainBackground` computed into the div element. And returned link is updated based on language.

**I have solved the problem by using class binding**. 1 class for Turkish lang, and main class for all other languages. And used them in conditional class binding. Solution:

```
:class="[isTurkishSite ? 'bg-turkish' : '']"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because of the semicolons you put at the end of url() directives, css rules set in object notation with Vue don't require semicolons :)

Comment: I have tested and worked. Thank you. But in first load it works with ending semicolons. That is why I cant get what is wrong) Anyway as you mention without semicolons it working both on first load and later changes.